# How to select only children in table

Tags: sql

I have the following table `taxonomy` which looks like:

```
taxonomy_id  | parent_id
------------------------
1            | 0
2            | 0
3            | 1
4            | 1
5            | 2
6            | 3
```

I want to select all items which are not parents, in the case 4,5 and 6. The first 3 items obviously are parents and I don't need them. What should be the query?

Comment: why is 4 in your result and 3 not?

Comment: @juergend: because 6's parent is 3.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT taxonomy_id, parent_id
FROM dbo.Taxonomy t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Taxonomy t2
    WHERE t1.taxonomy_id=t2.parent_id
)
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6024e/1/0)</kbd>

At least in SQL-Server this is the best approach: 
[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM taxonomy WHERE taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM taxonomy WHERE parent_id <> 0)
```

Comment: This selects all children without a top parent. OP wants all children without a child.

Answer (score 0):

```
select taxonomy_id
from taxonomy
where taxonomy_id not in
(
  select distinct parent_id from taxonomy
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you'll need to resort to a correlated subquery for this.

Either not exists:

```
select t.*
from taxonomy t
where t.parent_id <> 0
and not exists (select 1 from taxonomy t2 where t2.parent_id <> t.taxonomy_id)
```

Or not in:

```
select t.*
from taxonomy t
where t.parent_id <> 0
and t.taxonomy_id not in (select t2.parent_id from taxonomy t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
select * from taxonomy where taxonomy_id <> all (select parent_id from taxonomy)
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/281bec/1)</kbd>

Thanks for the link to the user [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) excellent service [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)